# jqGrid does not refresh with new data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am getting json data from the server by passing in a page number n which should get the nth 100 rows. After loading it once, and pressing the "next page" button, it seems to get the new data correctly (I output the first object in the new data when it is being refreshed) but it does not populate that data in my grid.

```
<div>
    <button id="refreshJobsButton">Refresh Jobs</button>
    <button id="nextPageJobsButton">Next page</button>
    <table id="JobTable"><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <div id="JobPager" class="ui-widget"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = 0;
$('#nextPageJobsButton').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s"
            }
    }).click(function(){
    page = page + 1;
$("#JobTable").jqGrid('GridUnload');
        refreshJob(page);
        });
};
        function refreshJob(page) {
            var $source = "ajax/refreshJob?page=" + page;

        $.ajax({
            url: $source,
            dataType: "json",
            success: populateJobs,
            error: handleAjaxError
        });
    }

        function populateJobs(jobs) {
    k = Object.keys(jobs)[0];
    l = Object.keys(jobs[k])[0];
    alert ("First job in list is " + jobs[k][l]); //Outputs correct job of that page

        $(function() {
            var grid = $('#JobTable');
            $('#JobTable').jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                editurl: 'ajax/modifyJob',
                mtype: 'POST',
                loadonce: false,
                datastr: jobs,
                height: 600,
                autowidth: true,
                forceFit: true,
                gridview: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: true,
                sortable: false,
                toppager: true,
                treeGrid: true,
                treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                treedatatype: 'POST',
                ExpandColumn: 'Job',
                ExpandColClick: true,
                colNames: [
                    "Id (hidden)",
                    "Job Type (hidden)"
                ],
                colModel: [{
                    name: 'id',
                    index: 'id',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'text',
                    key: true
                }, {
                    name: 'jobType',
                    index: 'jobType',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'text'
                }],
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function(obj) {
                        return obj;
                    },
                    page: function() {
                        return 1;
                    },
                    total: function() {
                        return 1;
                    },
                    records: function(obj) {
                        return obj.length;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Can anybody advise what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `$(function() {` in your code. It's the same as `$(document).ready(function() {`, but you have included the block `$(function() {` **inside of** `$(document).ready(function() {`. You should remove `$(function() {` (see near to the place where you creates the jqGrid).